# Who do these two C programs with a recursive function and static variable have different outputs?

Tags: c, function, static

This code gives output as 125

```
#include<stdio.h>

int func(int a)
{
    static int num = 2;
    if(a==0) return 1;
    num++; 
    return num*func(--a);
}

int main()
{
    printf("%d", func(3));
}
```

While this code gives output as 60

```
#include<stdio.h>

int func(int a)
{
    static int num = 2;
    if(a==0) return 1;
    return (++num)*func(--a);
}

int main()
{
    printf("%d", func(3));
}
```

In the first code I incremented `num` before return statement, in second code I pre-incremented `num` in the return statement.
The first code seems to be evaluating to 5*5*5, while the second evaluates to 3*4*5. Why is it so?

Comment: Put some `printf`s in `func` and find out.

Comment: There's 2 *side-effects* in `return (++num)*func(--a);`. They can be done in any order, ie `num` can change before or after `func()` is called. And the value of `num` changes the value of the function.

Comment: There's an important lesson here: *Don't write code like `return (++num)*func(--a);`*.  It's just too hard to understand.

Comment: Here's a checklist of things to avoid: recursion, local `static`, mixing ++/-- with other operators in the same expression, writing code relying on a certain order of evaluation. So basically everything in this function is considered bad practice in one way or another.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On this line in the second program:

```
return (++num)*func(--a);
```

The value of `num` is incremented as a side effect, *and* the function call to `func` also modifies `num`.

The evaluation of the individual operands of this expression are *unsequenced*, which means that either `num` may be evaluated first or that `func` may be called first.

The call to `func` does introduce a sequence point.  So if `++num` is evaluated first, the side effect of incrementing `num` is applied before `func` is actually called.  On the other hand, if the call to `func` is evaluated first, `num` will be modified inside of the function call and then the read and update of `num` will see the updated value.  However, there's no guarantee that one or the other will happen first.

So there's no undefined behavior here, however the result is **unspecified** due to the unsequenced evaluation of the subexpressions.

The first program has a similar issue, even though `num` isn't incremented in the same statement:

```
return num*func(--a);
```

Just as before, if `num` is evaluated first then the current value is seen.  If the function call is evaluated first, then the updated value of `num` will be read.

To get deterministic behavior from your program, you'll need to copy the current value of the static variable to a non-static variable and use that value to multiply by the function result.

```
int func(int a)
{
    static int num = 2;
    if(a==0) return 1;
    int num_tmp = ++num;
    return num_tmp*func(--a);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! What can I do in first program so that value of `num` is always taken first before evaluating `func(--a)? How can I specify the sequence?

Comment: @puneetred Copy the value to a non-static local variable.

Comment: thank you! that solved my problem